# Php - Twilio MMS not sending if image link is broken/unavailable

Tags: php, twilio, mms

I have an application that uses Twilio to send MMS messages. It works fine; however, when the image link provided is broken/unavailable, it does not continue to send the MMS.

In my application I have a module that sends the image to the server via FTP. From that, I get the URL of that image and attach it on the MMS message. For some reason, if the image doesn't successfully uploaded to the server via FTP, the image link will be broken, and thus it does not send the MMS.

Can you please help me resolving this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Reupload the image, when the link is broken? Just send the MMS anyways? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Megan from Twilio here.

Sending [MMS messages relies on the `MediaURL`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-conditional) thus if the URL you are trying to send through is broken, it will not work.

In the example:

```
$client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => "+16518675309", 
    'From' => "+14158141829", 
    'Body' => "Check out this awesome image!", 
    'MediaUrl' => "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",  
));
```

if the flickr image link were to break you would not receive the MMS portion of this message.

I've dealt with some tricky ways of handling image URLs via the file system in [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/11/getting-started-with-opencv-and-python-featuring-the-martian-2.html), perhaps you will need to finagle something similar into your code.

Hope this helps!